# How do I add borders between rows in css as in the picture below (red line- I need, gey line is now)

Tags: css, line, border, rows

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TIJ0R.png)

How do I add borders in css as in the picture below (red line- I need, gey line is now)

Comment: Can you please add the html you have? Technically, the answer to your current question is `border: 5px solid #ff0000;` but I would assume your HTML is more complex as a table.

Answer (score 0):

first of all create an unordered list and apply display flex and you can insert content in html. And you might need to add `display:flex;`in the list items if you have more than one element inside.

```
.menu_ul{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.menu_list_items{
    padding: 30px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
    border-right: none;
}
.menu_list_items:last-child{
    border-right: 2px solid rgb(128, 128, 128);
}
```

for the html,

```
<ul class="menu_ul">
    <li class="menu_list_items">Txt1</li>
    <li class="menu_list_items">Txt2</li>
    <li class="menu_list_items">Txt3</li>
    <li class="menu_list_items">Txt4</li>
</ul>
```

That will be the basic structure you want.